# Cypress: How to capture text from a selector on one page to use as text on another page

Tags: cypress

New cypress user here, I am aware that cypress does not handle variables like how testcafe and others do due to the asyn nature of it. Using the example given and what I could find I have this as an example:

`cy.get('selector').invoke('text').as('text_needed')`

`cy.get('@text_needed')`

`const txtneeded = this.text_needed`

`cy.log(txtneeded)`

This looks at a given selector, takes what it finds and uses it as text and set it as a variable usable at any time in the test and outputs it to the log. The plan is to use that text in a search filter in another page to find the item it references.

The problem is that it fails with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text_needed')`

Is this because the content of the selector is not assigned to text properly, the outer html is `<a data-v-78d50a00="" data-v-3d3629a7="" href="#">PO90944</a>` The `PO90944` is what I want to capture.

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save an alias and access it via `this.*` in the same execution context (callback) because it's a synchronous operation and your alias is not yet resolved at this time.
This is a correct way to go:

```js
cy.get('selector').invoke('text').as('text_needed')

cy.get('@text_needed').then(txtneeded => {
   cy.log(txtneeded)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to define `it` as traditional function, not as an arrow function as `this` context doesn't work as you'd expect there, more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Next, typically in a single test you should use .then() callback to perform additional actions on elements, and use aliases when you need to share context between hooks or different tests, so please consider the following:

```
// using aliases together with this within the single test won't work
cy.get(<selector>).invoke('text').as('text_needed')
cy.get('@text_needed').should('contain', 'PO90944') // works fine
cy.log(this.text_needed) // undefined

// this will work as expected
cy.get(<selector>).invoke('text').then(($el) => {
    cy.wrap($el).should('contain', 'PO90944'); // works fine
    cy.log($el) // works fine
});
```

Setting alias in `beforeEach` hook for example, would let you access `this.text_needed` in your tests without problems.

Everything nicely explained [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases).

Edit based on comments:

```
it('Some test', function() {
    cy.visit('www.example.com');
    cy.get('h1').invoke('text').as('someVar');
});

it('Some other test', function() {
    cy.visit('www.example.com');
    cy.log('I expect "Example Domain" here: ' + this.someVar);
});
```

And here's the output from cypress runner:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answers I got it working. I also read the information about aliases and variable which now makes more sense that I have a working example. Here is an expansion of the question: how do I store that variable for use in my other tests WITHOUT using beforeEach? The reason I ask this because that once that number is used the process I used to find it will no longer work since the entry is processed on the website. How do I store it as a global variable to be used in all my tests in the suite?

Comment: Should I write the variable to a file and read from the file for my other tests?

Comment: No, that's a valid case for aliases, as far as I know the tests in single file are executed in order, so define alias in first test, and in all the following tests access it simply with this.something. As I mentioned: "use aliases when you need to share context between hooks or different tests"

Comment: This assumes that all your tests that want to share some context are within the same spec file. Not really sure how to share it between different spec files, but I don't think you should try and do that anyway, sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: Hi Jovan, sadly, the alias defined in one test in a file is cleared before the next test in the same file. I have found multiple references to this online as well, in all cases the beforeEach method is suggested to keep an alias alive, which I cannot use in my case. I am stumped as to how I am supposed to test end to end for a process in smaller test units. The only way I can solve this is to either write one massive test which uses the same alias all the way through or to write to a file.

Comment: I will be looking into writing the variable to a file next since writing one big test is a recipe for disaster, one simple failure in such a test fails the entire test. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, I'm really not sure why this doesn't work for you, or maybe I missed something important you said, but this is definitely the way to go in general, I tried it multiple times, and just having simple spec file with two "it" declarations using traditional (!) functions allows me to specify alias in one test and have it available in another. I'll edit my answer to include a working example.

Comment: cy.get(tbody > :nth-child(1) > .is-sticky).invoke('text').as('product_code')

cy.log(this.product_code)

returns `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product_code')` for me ;-(

Comment: This whole adventure has opened my eyes to the use of a json file to hold attributes of a testing data item. It has blown my mind with the possibilities for testing, that I can have my own little captured database of the attributes of a test item that I can test against.

Comment: Jovan, if I change my test from a => to a function { format then using this.var does not return undefined anymore but something like cy.log(this.var) returns nothing at all. If I process it through a closure then it works, which is most frustrating since to write all the attributes of a test item to a file means using a massively nested closure for multiple variables. Thank you for your help so far, much appreciated.